# Trigger event for an svg element that moves behind another one?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

the desired output is for example: When the red masked rectangle is moving behind one of the "holes", the hole needs to change the fill (or some other attr).

Is it possible to add some sort of event that triggers when the moving_rect is entering/leaving the area of the hole element?

in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/qwertasyx/n9v7L95j/

also here as snippet:

```js
var draw = SVG('myDrawing').size('100%',200);

var rect_group = draw.group()

//we dont want to see this
var background = rect_group.rect(200,150).center(250,100).fill('#000')
// we want too see through those 'holes'
var hole1 = rect_group.rect(40,40).center(290,70 ).fill('#fff')
var hole2 = rect_group.rect(40,40).center(290,130).fill('#fff')
var hole3 = rect_group.rect(40,40).center(220,70 ).fill('#fff')
var hole4 = rect_group.rect(40,40).center(220,130).fill('#fff')

// object that we see through the holes
var moving_rect = draw.rect(40,40).fill('red').center(250,100)

//mask obj 
var mask = draw.mask()
$('#mask').on('click',function(e){
 mask.add(rect_group)
  moving_rect.maskWith(mask)
})

$('#animate').on('click',function(e){    moving_rect.animate(250).move(160,40).animate(250).move(250,40).animate(250).move(300,80).animate(250).move(250,160).animate(250).center(250,100)
})
```

```css
svg{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    <h5>Example svg -> click button for animation </h5><button id="mask" class="btn btn-primary">mask rect</button> <button id="animate" class="btn btn-primary">animate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="myDrawing"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Event - no. The nearest you can get would be the [isPointInFill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill) method, but support is patchy at the moment.

Comment: Why not? You just have to check whenever the rectangle moves whether or not one of these circles intersect with the rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I crafted together a solution where on every animation step it is checked if one of the rectangles (holes) is intersecting with the moving rectangle.
If an intersection is detected, it changes the fill color of the "holes".

```
    // animate()...
    .duringAll(function () {
        // get box of the rectangle
        var bbox = this.bbox()

        // intersection function. You should define it somewhere outside
        // instead of redefining every time
        var intersect = function(boxA, boxB) {
            return (boxA.x < boxB.x2 && boxA.x2 > boxB.x &&
            boxA.y < boxB.y2 && boxA.y2 > boxB.y) 
        }

        // go trough the boxes of every hole defined before
        boxes.forEach(function (el, index) {
            if(intersect(bbox, el)) {
                // change color of fill on intersection
                rects[index].fill('#555')
            } else {
                rects[index].fill('#fff')
            }
        })

    })
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Fuzzy/n9v7L95j/5/

It would be trivial to fire an event instead. You can just go:

```
this.fire('intersection', {index: index})

// then bind with
moving_rect.on('intersection', function (ev) {
    var index = ev.detail.index

    // do somthing
    rects[index].fill('#333')
})
```